# Date/Time syntax error 3144 on update

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am building a database with UI forms for employees to use. On several of them I have the date/time written into a table that works without issue.

```
txtrmopcsgstarttime=Now()
strsql = "UPDATE RMOP_csg_Daily_tbl SET Start_Time = '" & Me.txtrmopcsgstarttime & "' WHERE sysacct = [txtrmopcsgsysacct]"
DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
```

I am now creating a form where I am trying to create a tracking log with their username and a timestamp. I have tried using INSERT INTO and UPDATE both without success. I can get the username to write into the table just not the date/time.

```
Dim strsql As String
 txtAMSetup_CurrentDate = Now()
      strsql = "INSERT INTO AMSetupLog_tbl1 (User) VALUES ('" & Me.txtAMSetup_UserName.Value & "')"
      DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
      strsql = "UPDATE AMSetupLog_tbl1 SET Time = '" & Me.txtAMSetup_CurrentDate & "' WHERE USER = [txtAMSetup_UserName]"
      DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
```

The error I am receiving in this format is a 3144 syntax error. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: It's prefereable to use `CreateQueryDef` so you can pass parameters: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/142938. It also avoids Sql Injection vulnerability

Comment: Thanks. I ended up changing the Time field in the table to a different name and it worked successfully. I will look into CreateQueryDef, however, as well.